# Django rest framework best way to validate POST request parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

When I receive a `POST` request on a Django REST framework `APIView` class, I would like to filter/validate the parameters that are passed to prevent them from being modified. For example, for this serializer:

```py
class MediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Media
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'content', 'url', 'createdByUser', 'karma', 'type', 'issue', 'creationDate', 'updatedDate')
```

Some parameters such as the `id`, `creationDate` or `createdByUser` shouldn't be modified. So for my class `class MediaDetail(APIView)` I have:

```py
def validateRequest(self):
        user = self.request.data.get('createdByUser', None)
        karma = self.request.data.get('karma', None)
        creationDate = self.request.data.get('creationDate', None)

        if user is not None or karma is not None or creationDate is not None:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@method_decorator(login_required)
def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
        self.validateRequest()
        media = self.get_object(pk)
        self._throwIfNotMediaAuthor(media, request.user)

        serializer = MediaSerializer(media, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            # serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Is there a better way to make this validation? Maybe on the serializer? I couldn't find enough documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`read_only_fields`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields) parameter on your serializer's `Meta`.

Example on how to use inside your current view (modified it a little assuming you want to create an object when `POST`ing as per [REST's guidelines](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)):

```
class MediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Media
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'karma', 'createdByUser', 'creationDate')
        ...

@method_decorator(login_required)
def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
        serializer = MediaSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(createdByUser=request.user, creationDate=timezone.now().date(), karma=initial_value)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: And if I would like to modify one on specific cases (or when i'm creating an object), should I modify directly on the model?

Comment: you can override the `update` or `create` methods on the serializer and validate the data by hand then.
you can also choose not to use the `read_only_fields` and do the validation by hand right away (while also overriding the `update`/ `create` methods) by overriding the `validate` method.
an example: you can pass additional fields to your `serializer.save()` method - so for instance, if you have the `creation_date` and `user` fields as `read_only`, you could use the `serializer.is_valid()` to validate and then serializer.save(user=request.user, creation_date=timezone.now().date()`.

Comment: Sorry have you info of how to do that? Can i for example just override the `create` method? 
If I understand well, I can let the `read_only_fields` and use just ` serializer.save(user=request.user, creation_date=timezone.now().date()` but this doesn't work. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save

Comment: Finally the workaround is **use `read_only_fields`** and in the create function "hardcode" the needed fields **after data validation**, for example: `serializer.save(createdByUser=createdByUser,
                            issue=issue,
                            creationDate=creationDate,
                            updatedDate=updatedDate)` **without overriding `update`, `create` or `save` methods**

Comment: I updated my answer when you asked for more info - guess it didn't trigger any notification on your end, my bad! :/

Comment: Coming from Laravel I feel like something is wrong with Django, why to merge validation function into serializer in the first place, this are two very different things.